# Getting multiple variables from a read in line

Tags: c, numbers

I am having trouble getting multiple number vars from a read in line. For a single value I can do strtol(), but how can I get the float and long values of a sentence that is similar to as follows.

> Please aim 3.567 degrees at a height of 5 meters.

I tried doing two different calls to my buffer sentence, however it got neither of my values. I have no issues with get single values, but with to, I get 0.000 from my strtof call and 0 from mmy strtol call.

Comment: Will the input always start with `"Please aim "` and then be followed by a floating-point number, and then contain the string `"  degrees at a height of "`, and then an integer, and then the string `" meters.\n"`? Or does your program have to be flexible to allow different input before and after the numbers?

Comment: "I tried doing two different calls to my buffer sentence," --> post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input always starts with the string `"Please aim "`, followed by a floating-point number, followed by the string `" degrees at a height of "`, followed by an integer, followed by the string `" meters."`, then you can use the functions `strtof` and `strtol`, but you must skip the strings first, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *line = "Please aim 3.567 degrees at a height of 5 meters.";

    char *part1 = "Please aim ";
    char *part2 = " degrees at a height of ";
    char *part3 = " meters.";

    float degrees;
    long height;

    size_t part1_len = strlen( part1 );
    size_t part2_len = strlen( part2 );
    size_t part3_len = strlen( part3 );

    //make p point to start of line
    char *p = line;

    char *q;

    //verify that the line starts with part1 and skip it
    if ( strncmp( p, part1, part1_len ) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to find part1!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    p += part1_len;

    //attempt to convert degrees value and skip it
    degrees = strtof( p, &q );
    if ( p == q )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error converting degrees!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    p = q;

    //verify that the line continues with part2 and skip it
    if ( strncmp( p, part2, part2_len ) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to find part2!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    p += part2_len;

    //attempt to convert height value and skip it
    height = strtol( p, &q, 10 );
    if ( p == q )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error converting height!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    p = q;

    //verify that the line continues with part3 and skip it
    if ( strncmp( p, part3, part3_len ) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to find part3!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    p += part3_len;

    //verify that we have reached the end of the string
    if ( *p != '\0' )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unexpected character encountered!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //print the results
    printf(
        "Results:\n"
        "Degrees: %f\n"
        "Height: %ld\n",
        degrees, height
    );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Results:
Degrees: 3.567000
Height: 5
```